# accessing previous methods in a chain (Ruby (on Rails))

Tags: ruby-on-rails, method-chaining

Lets say I have classes for employees, managers, and companies.  These inherit from `ActiveRecord` and are all associated as you might expect.

I have two instances of the `Employee` class, `bob` and `jane`.  They both work for the same company but have different managers.

I want to be able to call `bob.company.x` or `jane.company.x` and get different results because, although they work for the same company, they have different managers.  There are other limitations that prevent me from just defining x as a method for employees and calling `bob.company_x`, which I realize would be simpler in this example.

Is there any way that I can know, within my method definition for x, which employee started this method chain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you propose cannot be done in a clean and simple way, and aside of that, is counter-intuitive.

```
class Employee
  belongs_to :company
  belongs_to :manager
end
```

is the only clean solution. This has the relations cleanly defined. These relations need to be available anyway: how would you know which is the manager for `bob`?

A solution, as you propose, where you can write `bob.company.my_manager` does not make sense, because `bob.company` is his company, and at that level (`Company`) there is no more knowledge of `bob`.

For completeness sake: actually a manager is an employee itself, so we would write that relation a bit differently:

```
class Employee
  belongs_to :manager, :class => Employee
end
```

(and in your `employees` table you need to add a field `manager_id`).

Hope this helps.

Comment: My question is not about how to set up the associations.  The situation is contrived to get at my point of whether or not a method is aware of the scope in which it was called such that x will know it was called through bob and not through jane when calling bob.company.x

Comment: I think i was being clear: imho there is no way of knowing whether `x`, being a method on a `company`, was called throught `companies[11].x`, `Company.new.x`, `bob.company.x`. It is possible if a `company` only has one `employee`. But that defeats the purpose. So since you ask the question, i think your associations are wrong. Hence the suggestions. A manager of an employee is not linked to a company (alone), but to the employee. I have no idea what your experience with OO is.

Comment: Thanks.  I just wanted to know if that was possible.